# VB.net Login Access level MS Access

Tags: vb.net

So basically i wanted it have a User and Admin Access level so when i click login in my form it will check if the username and the password is set on admin then go to admin form then if its user it will go to user form... i have here my codes and it works perfectly its just that i cannot figure out how the system will check if a pass and username is a user or a admin before going to another form here is the code btw
Thanks in advance!

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btLogin.Click
    If tbUser.Text = Nothing Or tbPass.Text = Nothing Then
        MsgBox("Please Enter Valid Username and Password", MsgBoxStyle.Exclamation)
    Else
        If connection.State = ConnectionState.Closed Then
            connection.Open()
        End If
        Dim cmd As New OleDbCommand("select count(*) from dbLogin where dbUser=? and dbPass=?", connection)
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@1", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = tbUser.Text
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@2", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = tbPass.Text
        Dim count = Convert.ToInt32(cmd.ExecuteScalar())

        If (count > 0) Then
            MsgBox("Login Succeed", MsgBoxStyle.Information)
            Menuvb.Show()
            Me.Hide()
        Else
            MsgBox("Account not Registered", MsgBoxStyle.Critical)
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: textboxes texts will never be nothing, at most an empty string. use `String.IsNullOrWhitespace(tbUser.Text)` also use `OrElse` to save the extra comparison.

Comment: Please don't store your passwords in cleartext in your database. you can use https://www.nuget.org/packages/BCrypt.Net-Next/ for your password hashing needs. it's pretty much the industry standard to use bcrypt now. More documentation and examples on the git page here: https://github.com/BcryptNet/bcrypt.net

Comment: my codes works perfectly right now but i do now know the codes that allow the program to check if a certain data in that is inputted in the textboxes is a user or a admin im kinda new in vb.net and im just trying to learn from different videos so. yah :D

Comment: I understand your problem, I just point out the other things I see.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of simply checking if the user exists, you should look at the return from the database. Provided you have a field for the user's role, say `dbRole`. You can use the following code:

```
Dim connectionString As String = "provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;data source=" & dbPath
Dim connection As New OleDbConnection(connectionString)
connection.Open()
Dim cmd As New OleDbCommand("", connection)
Dim adapter As New OleDbDataAdapter(cmd)

Dim SQL As String = "SELECT * FROM dbLogin WHERE dbUser = @USER"
adapter.SelectCommand.CommandText = SQL
adapter.SelectCommand.Parameters.Add("@USER", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = userName
Dim dtTbl As New DataTable()
adapter.Fill(dtTbl)
connection.Close()

If (dtTbl.Rows.Count() = 0) Then
    ' user not found, don't tell your user or they might be able to brute force all valid user names. just say login failed as if the password were wrong.
Else If (dtTbl.Rows.Count() > 1) Then
    ' db error. user should only appear once
Else
    ' 1 user found.
    Dim row As DataRow = dtTbl.Rows(0)
    Dim dbPwd As String = If(IsDBNull(row("dbPass")), String.Empty, row("dbPass").ToString())
    Dim dbRole As String = If(IsDBNull(row("dbRole")), String.Empty, row("dbRole").ToString())
    '
    ' Do what you need to do here. (if dbRole = "admin", password check, etc)
End If
```

It might be a good idea to have a function that takes an SQL query and a `Dictionary(Of String, Tuple(Of Object, OleDbType))` and returns the data table for you.

```
''' <summary>
''' Fills a DataTable from an SQL Query
''' </summary>
''' <param name="SQL">SQL Query, Parameters start with @</param>
''' <param name="parameters">Parameters. Key = parameterName, without @. value = (parameter value, OleDbType)</param>
''' <returns>Filled DataTable</returns>
Public Function QueryDatasource(SQL As String, parameters As Dictionary(Of String, Tuple(Of Object, OleDbType))) As DataTable

    Dim ret As DataTable = New DataTable()
    Dim cmd As OleDbCommand ' IDbCommand
    Dim adapter As OleDbDataAdapter ' IDbDataAdapter

    connection.Open() ' connection is an OleDbConnection in class scope here.

    cmd = New OleDbCommand("", connection)

    adapter = New OleDbDataAdapter(cmd)
    adapter.SelectCommand.CommandText = SQL

    If (parameters IsNot Nothing) Then
        For Each parameterName As String In parameters.Keys
            If (SQL.Contains("@" + parameterName)) Then
                adapter.SelectCommand.Parameters.Add("@" + parameterName, parameters(parameterName).Item2).Value = parameters(parameterName).Item1
            End If
        Next
    End If

    adapter.Fill(ret)

    connection.Close()
    Return ret
End Function
```

As a side note: Never *ever* store your passwords as cleartext in a database. Use a digest function such as [BCrypt](https://github.com/BcryptNet/bcrypt.net). BCrypt-Next is a nuget available for DotNet and is easy to use.